# Is there any way to use DISTINCT in xmlagg function in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I used the following command.

```sql
select col1, col2, XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E, colname || ',')).EXTRACT('//text()')
from table
group by col1, col2
```

output:

```
col1      col2      col3

KOCHI   ERNAKULAM   residential, commercial, residential, residential
```

But i need the following output as

```
col3 :

residential, commercial.
```

I tried using DISTINCT in subquery but not getting the required output. Any help?

Comment: Yeah. Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `distinct` in the sub-query as follows:

```
select col1, col2, XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E, colname || ',')).EXTRACT('//text()')
from (select distinct col1, col2, colname from table)
group by col1, col2
```

Answer (score 1):

how about use the `regexp_replace` function? for example

```
select
col1,
col2,
regexp_replace(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E, colname || ',')).EXTRACT('//text()'),'([^,]+)(,\1)+', '\1') as colname_list
from table
group by col1, col2
```

Answer (score 0):

First select distinct values, then apply `XMLAGG`, e.g.

```
select col1, col2, XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E, colname || ',')).EXTRACT('//text()')
from (select distinct col1, col2, colname
      from table 
     )
group by col1, col2
```

---

Though, if the resulting string doesn't exceed 4000 characters, consider using `LISTAGG`:

```
select col1, col2, LISTAGG(colname, ',')) within group (order by null)
from (select distinct col1, col2, colname
      from table 
     )
group by col1, col2
```

Answer (score 0):

Although a subquery with `DISTINCT` works in this case, it is not a generalizable solution.  It can interfere with other columns that you might want to include in the query.

`XMLAGG()` ignores `NULL` values.  So a more general approach uses `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
select col1, col2,
       XMLAGG(CASE WHEN SEQNUM. = 1 THEN XMLELEMENT(E, colname || ',') END).EXTRACT('//text()')
from (select t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2, colname ORDER BY colname) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by col1, col2
```